# Как обработать кнопку в RecyclerView чтобы она удаляла конкретную запись из sqlite

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

В `RecyclerView` есть кнопка, при нажатию на нее должно произойти удаление текущий записи, которую я храню в sqlite. Создал метод который будет удалять саму запись:

```
public void deleteFruit(Fruit fruit) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT, KEY_ID_FRUIT + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(fruit.getId())});
    db.close();
}
```

Но как ему передать параметр именно того элемента, который хочу удалить не знаю.

И где его лучше вызвать этот метод: в главном активити или в адаптере?

Код адаптера:

Comment: Покажите код адаптера.

Comment: Я обновил в вопросе

Answer (score 3):

В методе `onClick(...)` получите текущий объект и передайте его в метод удаления:

```
Fruit fruit = fruits.get(position);
deleteFruit(fruit);
```

При этом не забудьте удалить сам объект из `fruits` и обновить данные:

```
fruits.remove(postion);
RecyclerAdapter.this.notifyItemRemoved(postion);
```

Comment: dbHelperFruit = new DBHelperFruit(this); У меня проблема с инициализацией, что нужно передать в параметр ?

Comment: @Fedia, С архитектурной точки зрения это все неправильно и криво. А так можете попробовать передать туда `v.getContext()`.

Comment: А не могли б помочь с архитектурой проекта ? А то и сам понимаю что все криво, но по другому не умею.

Comment: @Fedia, По поводу правильной архитектуры – это очень объемная тема. Почитайте книги по программированию под Android.